# wget from Google shopping list

Tags: python, terminal, wget, thermal-printer

I have a thermal printer that runs scripts daily to print my tasks (from a taskwarrior server) and weather.  The next step is to try and get it to print my shopping list.

There is no API for the shopping list, that I can find anyway, and my wget foo is weak.  What I'd like to do is scrape the list from https://shoppinglist.google.com/lists/default and I can process it down to a format suitable for the thermal printer.

I have tried variations on the following:

```
wget --user USER --password PASS https://shoppinglist.google.com/lists/default
```

But I keep getting stumped by the google login page.

Can anyone make any suggestions for how I could tackle this?  My output will then get parsed through a python script to eventually look something like this:

```
- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
```

Comment: You need to obtain OAuth2 token instead of using login and password - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2